# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: php

```
<?php
include"include/db.php";
                $sql=mysql_query("select * from order where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0") or die(mysql_error());
                $i=0;
                $sum=0;
                $sum2=0;

                while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
                {
                $sum2+=$rows['tedad'];
                $sum+=getproductPrice($rows['pid']);
                echo "<tr style=\"border:#00CCFF thin dotted\"><td><img src='images/bullet_delete.png' ></td>
                <td align=center>".$rows['tedad']."</td>
                <td align=left>".getproductPrice($rows['pid'])."</td>
                <td align=right>".getproductName($rows['pid'])."</td>
                <td align=center>".++$i."</td></tr>";

?>
```

This is my code, how do I correct it wrong
my error is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order where user='zahra20' and flag=0' at line 1

Comment: Please show your Query, with SELECT  BLA BLA, we can't answer anything from that showen code, we need the query ^^

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("select * from order where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your query:

```
"select * from order where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0"
```

There are a couple of things wrong here.

First, `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  In order to use it as an identifier you need to enclose it in back-ticks:

```
"select * from `order` where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0"
```

Second, your query is *wide open* to [**SQL Injection Attacks**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  That session value [could have anything in it](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Since you're effectively executing that value *as code* then you don't control the syntax of the code you're executing.  I recommend fixing that.

Comment: I do not understand your second solution can explain once again

Comment: @zahra: The solution is to enclose identifiers in back-ticks.  This *must* be done for identifiers which are reserved words, but can be done for any identifier.  (An identifier is a table name or a column name.)  *In addition to this*, you should read the supplied link regarding SQL injection attacks.  Your code is currently vulnerable to them.  This means your users can execute code on your server without asking.  You'll want to fix that.  The linked article will help.

Comment: sorry,My problem is not resolved

Comment: @zahra: Can you be more specific?  What's changed?  How have you updated the code and what is the new behavior?  I can't see your screen, you have to describe the problem.

Comment: Why, when I delete the following code gives the error :or die(mysql_error()) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\shopping\sabad-u.php on line 47

Comment: @zahra: That means the value of `$sql` is a boolean, most likely `false`.  Which means the SQL query is failing.  Use `mysql_error()` to get the error which explains why the SQL query is failing.  Update your question to include the updated code and the updated error.  Again, I can't advise you on an error that you're not showing.

Comment: I use mysql_error() and error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''order' where user='zahra20' and flag=0' at line 1

Comment: @zahra: Then you didn't apply the solution in this answer, which would explain why the problem isn't resolved.  Did you change your code at all?  If so, show the updated code in your question.  I really don't know how to explain this any more clearly... *I can't tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing.*  ***I can't see your screen.***

Comment: this is my code :
<?php
include"include/db.php";
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from 'order' where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0") or die(mysql_error());
     $i=0;
     $sum=0;
     $sum2=0;
     
     while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
     }
?>

Comment: @zahra: You used single-quotes instead of back-ticks.  Single-quotes are used to wrap a string.  Use back-ticks to wrap a database identifier.

Comment: I do not understand back-ticks means

Comment: @zahra: It's a character on the keyboard.  On a US keyboard it's to the left of the "1".  You can feel free to *copy* and *paste* the back-ticks used in my answer.  I'm not sure what your browser is showing you, but on mine there is a *clear* difference between a single-quote and a back-tick.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `order` where user='".$_SESSION['user']."' and flag=0") or die(mysql_error());
```

This should work, since you're having a table called 'order', you have to use '`' before and after the name, **BECAUSE** there's a SQL function called order, and since you can't SELECT * FROM ORDER, because ORDER is a function, then you're getting an error.

You should also consider using PDO or MySQLi for queries, since old mysql is not secure at all.